# Has any polytheistic religion throughout history given relevance to a god or goddess of cruelty?

Tags: religion

What I particularly want to know is whether any god or major entity in any religion has been primarily associated with cruelty, understood as taking pleasure in causing pain.

I have been unable to find anything on my own on Google. Perhaps a list of major deities and their defining traits as a resource could be enough. If such a deity does exist, I would appreciate a list if possible.

Comment: Can you define cruelty a bit? There are God's of war which you could consider cruel, or are you looking for ________ the god of cruelty?

Comment: Not entirely sure this is history.  Mythology might be more appropriate.   Sekhmet perhaps?  Artemis to unwelcome suitors? The ensuing arguments are certainly not resolves let through historical sources & methods.

Comment: @EvanM The latter. A deity focused on cruelty, understood as "taking pleasure in causing pain or suffering to others".

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I posted my question here because I saw other questions related to mythology, and this one seemed to fit. I believe that whether such a deity existed or not is a matter of historical importance, however small.

Comment: I would have to agree with @MarkC.Wallace on this one. That being said, Tartarus, maybe a fit for what you are looking for. He was the Roman's answer for Hell and Satan. Let me know if that matches what you are looking for.

Comment: @EvanM I believe Tartarus is more fitting for a general entity related to evil, but not in the sense I was looking for. I am seeking either a list of those gods/demigods that fit what I have described, or a rather definitive "no".

Comment: @Thelightbringer , then you are looking at a no. Fundamentally this wouldn't exist. Historically speaking you have 3 types/personalities in these religions. The builder, the helper, and the punisher. If you are looking for something outside of the realm of punishment you won't find it. I agree with Mark at this point I think this now belongs in the mythology SE. Voting to move.

Comment: @EvanM is there a help page about moving questions?

Comment: @AChildofGod I am pretty sure that is either the job of a moderator or of a member who is above 3,000 rep points.

Comment: @EvanM but is there any documentation about it?